# SPRESENSE の電源として microUSB と Vout ピンを同時に接続した場合はどうなるのか？

Tags: spresense

質問場所違いの可能性がありますが、ご回答いただけたら幸いです。

SPRESNESEには、公式より給電方法に関してメインボードおよび拡張ボードのmicroUSB端子と拡張ボードのVoutピンへの入力が挙げられています。

仮にVoutピンに乾電池から電源供給をしつつ、microUSB端子とPCを接続した場合は正常に動作するのでしょうか。
私個人の予測では電源の二重供給となり、故障する可能性があると考えています。

ご回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 説明資料に書いてあるこれでしょう。[2.2.6.1. Spresense拡張ボードを使用する場合](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/introduction_ja.html#_spresense%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88) `この電源供給と micro USBコネクタからの電源供給と同時に行う場合には、VOUTピンに逆流防止回路を挿入してください。` それからspresense関連の質問は [アプリケーション開発に関するお問い合わせ](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/support/spresense-programming-support-on-stack-overflow/) の範囲と考えてください。

Answer (score 1):

SPRESNESEの回路図を見たわけではないですが、コメントの提示内容から察するにUSBの電源とVoutは直結されてるものと推測されます

それを前提に言うと、
両方を同時に供給した場合は、双方同じ電圧であれば何も起こりません。
しかし、双方の電源投入順序がちがうとか、電圧が違う、という場合は、電圧が高い方から低い方に無制限に電流が流れてしまう、事が考えられます
まあ、それがまともな電源であれば、保護回路が働いて何事も起こりません、が、そうではない場合、故障に繋がったりする場合があります